# Power Automate Desktop - Creating a UI Selector From an Accessibility Insights for Windows Report

Tags: accessibility-insights

I am using the [Accessibility Insights for Windows](https://accessibilityinsights.io/docs/en/windows/overview/) tool as a method to determine the most effective selector when using Power Automate Desktop.  I have a Pulse VPN app that I can launch but cannot click the Connect button.  I can use the UI automation recorder to click the button but after a reboot, the selector no longer works. While I understand web and jQuery selectors, I don't know how to write UI element selectors.  Any insight is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no generally accepted Windows analog to selectors. WinAppDriver includes a concept called [xPath](https://help.cycleautomation.com/hc/en-us/articles/360032204652-How-To-Use-WinAppDriver-UI-Recorder-to-Record-xPath) that attempts to solve this problem, but it's tightly bound to a specific version and language of an app, and only a few platforms (mainly WinAppDriver) use it.

Accessibility Insights support for xPath was requested in [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/accessibility-insights-windows/issues/535). We triaged it and decided that we'd leave that for a community contribution. Nobody ever picked it up and it was eventually closed after someone observed that WinAppDriver was no longer in active development.

Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

[Dave Tryon](https://github.com/DaveTryon), Accessibility Insights team

Comment: Thank you @DaveTyron for the great info!